# For power comparisons, is transistor count proportional to CPU capacitance?

Tags: integrated-circuit, capacitance, power-consumption

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU_power_dissipation#Sources):

> The dynamic power consumed by a CPU is approximately proportional to the CPU frequency, and to the square of the CPU voltage
>   $$P ∝ CV^2f  $$
>   where \$C\$ is the capacitance, \$f\$ is frequency, and \$V\$ is voltage.

I would like to compare the ARM Cortex A7 to the A15. In particular, comparing the complexities of the two cores with different transistor count.

A7: 8-stage in-order-pipeline => extremely simple => less logic on the chip needed
A15: complex, out-of-order pipeline => more transistors on the chip

Same can be said for the branch-prediction-unit, the L1-caches, etc...

So, would it be right to say, that the A7 has a much simpler logic and therefore
fewer transistors that need to be powered, and this results in a lower capacitance => less power consumption?

PS: the A7 running on lower frequencies is another fact that I don't want to compare here since, even on same frequencies, the A7 uses much less power then the A15.

Comment: Might want to fix your equation to match your words. Something like \$P \propto fCV^2 \$

Comment: Your probably not going to find C, but the other parameters are all known and P is measurable. That's how I would approach this. Every transistor has some capacitance associated with it, but trying to compare the inner workings of architecture seems a little arcane. A dynamic load can be thought of as a variable resistor or a resistor and capacitor with changing capacitance, but just an easy way to create a simple model of a complicated system.

Comment: The formula reflects the charging and discharging of capacitors at the gates of transistors. But for a complex system, you can't know how many transistors are switching at any given time, and even those who switch, won't switch at the same frequency (they won't switch at all at a given frequency, the switching of transistors of a complex system will most of the time follow an almost random behavior that cannot be represented by a 'frequency' which is repetitive over time). Actually the accurate characterization of power consumption of devices like FPGAs and ASICs is an incredibly tough task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something interesting to note here. Without the clock, the CPU would not be a capacitor. The capacitence dynamically changes (within a upper and lower bound) with the 'load' it's being put under. I'm guessing you're referring to the maximum power that a processor will use.

In your case, No, the transistor count is not porportional to capacitence. Many other things may vary between the two processors, including: Architecture (die size), Cache size, leakage current and even Load tolerance. Comparing two different generations of microarchitecture is not a good way to learn a concept.

To try and explain, Here is an example.

The energy in any capacitor is:
$$E=\frac{1}{2}CV^{2}$$
where E is in joules. A processor can be thought of as a capacitor that fills itself with electricity to perform a single calculation, and then empties that electricity with each cycle. To put this into perspective, imagine a [simple computer that runs on marbles](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wIKah9aVlm4). The marbles are electrons, and the switches are transistors. The marbles will pass through the machine, and come out the exit, reguardless of conditions. However, certain computers will take in more marbles at once. The measure of how many marbles run through is capacitence. The energy shift (\$K_{e1}+P_{e1} = K_{e2} + P_{e2}\$) in each marble is Voltage. Now, to get Power, we must devide by time (\$P=\frac{E}{t}\$). Well, we don't nessicarily have a time constant, but we have how often marbles are put in, which is measurued as a frequency (\$t^{-1}\$). Thus, we can conclude that \$P = Ef\$, and thus conclude that:

$$P∝Ef=\frac{1}{2}CV^{2}f$$

Now, Certain marble computers will vary in speed, frequency, delta E, number of marbles, so on. and depending on how the logic gates are arranged inside one of these computers,  the computers themselves may use more or less power. But more gates does not nessecarily mean more power.

Answer (score 0):

The appropriate way to come up with power measurements is not only to look at the total nodal cap, but also the activity factor, or "alpha" of each node.  Alpha is between 0 and 1 and is proportional to the percentage of the time (statistically) that the node switches.

It turns your formula into:

$$
 P ∝ \sum_{n=0}^N C_n*\alpha_n*V^2*f
$$

Where \$ C_n \$ is the nodal cap and \$ \alpha_n \$ is the activity factor of this node (relative to the main clock frequency, \$ f \$).

So, the total power is not really proportional to the number of transistors; since each transistor added does not necessarily have an equal chance of switching per cycle, nor the same nodal cap.

As a simple numerical example, assume each transistor has the exact same capacitances (all parasitic as well) and the power added by each transistor is 1.  Now a design with 100 transistors that switch every cycle will be '100' power.  But a design with 240 transistors that only switch 33% of the time consumes a power of '80'.  Obviously simplistic but it gives the general idea.

There are various tools that come up with \$ \alpha \$ for each node by various means.  For example, propagating a bunch test vectors through the design and literally measuring how often they switch in simulations empirically.  The more sophisticated methods will start from the beginning of the design and push each alpha value all the way through.

The best way to figure out which processor consumes less power, is to just look up the specs.  All commerical processors are tested a lot, and even the IC companies use the post-silicon data to amend their models!

It would be very impressive if, without any access to the models used processor, nor deep knowledge regarding the architectural implementation, you could come up with an accurate power measurement to compare two processors.